# 2000's comic book - policeman on day off takes down several mutants, including a giant, possibly in Chicago

Tags: story-identification, comics, mutant

So, there's this comic book I read a few months ago, which was quite entertaining, but I can't find its title anymore. I've tried Googling it with filters targeting the site I read it on, but no luck.

## General info:

- As stated above, I read it 2-3 months ago, but I think it wasn't on its release date. Could have been published during the last 10 years IMO.
- Read it in English on readcomiconline.to, and I'm pretty sure English was the original language.
- In color.

## Plot:

Some police cop, let's name him Bob, is on his day off when he witnesses an arrest go wrong, IE the guy being arrested has stone-hard skin and bullets bounces off him. He helps the task force handling him by throwing a glass bottle at him, figuring that he actually takes the consistance of what he's making contact with. Later on, Bob defeats another "mutant", this time a giant one, IIRC by making him ingest explosives hidden in a car/huge box. He's broadcasted on TV.

He's accompanied by a girl, let's call her Alice. At some point, they're in a stadium, supposed to be rescued or joined by a science team, but part of them dies. (this point is a bit blurry, but what I do remember is that it was quite a mess)

In the end,

> the mutant threat can be stopped by emitting some frequency from the top of a tower, using a remote. However the remote falls from the tower, but Bob jumps, catches it, presses the button and saves the day. (and then, I assume, makes quite a stain when he crashes on the road, but that wasn't shown...)

## Additional info:

- Mutants I remember: the skin-becomes-material-I-touch one, a flying man (who's actually crazy, flies through an helicopter at some point, and counters Bob at the end), a burning woman, the giant mutant (can't remember if male or female);
- Possibly in Chicago since the burning woman was nicknamed Mrs O'Leary - also, Bob and the firemen trapped her on an island;
- I think there was a mutant kid Bob had to shoot... Not sure if it was a kid though;
- a homeless man was able to generate a "leave me the f*** alone" kind of Black bubble... I think;
- The town was about to be nuked in the end;
- When entering the tower, Alice pranks Bob into thinking he forgot the batteries for the remote.

It's not even about wanting to re-read it (though I will), but it frustrates me to remember that much detail and not be able to find what it was. Hence, eternal gratitude to whoever calms down my nitpicking brain :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it! *Dominion* (2007), by Keith Giffen. Well, what I thought were mutants were actually alien microbes. That happens.

Back cover summary, which is more accurate than [the ComicVine one](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/dominion/4050-23463/):

> An alien virus is spreading uncontrollable superpowers through the city of Chicago.
>
> Handling intense situations is just part of the job for police officer Dick Urbanski. But now that his city's been quarantined, he faces a crisis unlike any ever seen on Earth. Despite the help of Dr. Ai Tanaka, Dick is unable to keep millions of panicked, superpowered citizens under control. Can he stay alive long enough to find a cure - or will the government be forced to blow Chicago off the map?

Other than this mutant/alien thing, I actually got that pretty right...

- > Some police cop, let's name him Bob, is on his day off when he witnesses an arrest go wrong, IE the guy being arrested has stone-hard skin and bullets bounces off him.

  Indeed, that skin hardness comes from the guy's ability to turn into what he touches; here, a concrete wall, which gives him said resistance:

  [image: guy with stone-hard skin]
- > He helps the task force handling him by throwing a glass bottle at him, figuring that he actually takes the consistance of what he's making contact with.

  Dick empties a beer bottle and aims for the guy's head. The guy turns into glass, and shatters under the police officers' bullets.

  [image: previous guy turns into glass and shatters]
- > Later on, Bob defeats another "mutant", this time a giant one, IIRC by making him ingest explosives hidden in a car/huge box. He's broadcasted on TV.

  That one isn't exactly family-friendly, so I'm not backing up the point with the scene's panel. However, here's what the giant... *creature* looks like.

  [image: giant creature smashes a car]
- > At some point, they're in a stadium, supposed to be rescued or joined by a science team, but part of them dies.

  Indeed, Dick (previously known as Bob) and Ai (previously known as Alice) are waiting for a CDC team to land in a football stadium. The helicopters draw the attention of a telekinetic mutant, which, like all newly superpowered Chicago citizens, is seriously wicked. Long story short, the CDC team is wiped clean (well, not so clean), and only a handful of them stay alive.
- > However the remote falls from the tower, but Bob jumps, catches it, presses the button and saves the day.

  Just as it happened. Because, physics!

  [image: main character saves the day]
- > Possibly in Chicago since the burning woman was nicknamed Mrs O'Leary - also, Bob and the firemen trapped her on an island.

  Indeed in Chicago. For the explanation, the legend goes that Mrs O'Leary's cow kicked the lamp, thus setting fire to the barn, which spread out to the whole city in the biggest fire Chicago ever knew. Hence, when a mutated woman is walking around covered in flames, she's nicknamed Mrs O'Leary.

  Figuring out that she won't cross water, the main character urges the firemen to corner her on [Navy Pier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navy_Pier), and destroy the bridge - so I had the "island" thing partially wrong.

  [image: Mrs O'Leary trapped on Navy Pier turned into an island]
- > I think there was a mutant kid Bob had to shoot... Not sure if it was a kid though.

  There was. The kid was bullied on a daily basis, and when the alien microbe landed on Earth, he turned into some monster with a swollen throat, instantly killing his bullies, and a bunch of other people afterwards. He's the only mutant we see who's not entirely driven mad - he's scared but does not want to go and wreck havok willingly.

  However, he's still a danger, being unable to control his powers, so Richard shoots him. Once again, I'm not including a picture of a kid being shot at point blank.
- > a homeless man was able to generate a "leave me the f*** alone" kind of Black bubble...

  Even more, said bubble was able to took out a S.W.A.T. team, not only because the light turned out, but because the guy became "crazy" with the years, and this craziness turned into a power manifests through chaos.

  [image: homeless man with a black bubble]
- > When entering the tower, Alice pranks Bob into thinking he forgot the batteries for the remote.

  [image: Ai pranks Richard into thinking he forgot the batteries for the remote]

---

As to how I found it, I'm afraid there is not much Google-Fu involved. I was reading a *Batman* issue featuring Clayface, and remembered that I read this comic around the release date of *Detective Comics Annual #1* (which is to say January). So, I just browsed back through *a lot* of "newest release" pages on the site I read on, and found it.

Comment: For the record, that was a badass action-packed comics. Definitely worth the read if you enjoy the American way of solving issues by blowing stuff up!